# Replacing an object name with characters in a loop

Tags: r

I am new to R from SAS. I would use a global macro variable in SAS to accomplish this but haven't found the means in R yet. I want to figure out how to use a loop, or some other R capability, to simplify my code by replacing an object name, that is character, along with attaching the name to additional text ('.sum'). If I start with the code below:

```
RED.sum <- aggregate(y ~ x, data = RED, FUN = "mean")
ORANGE.sum <- aggregate(y ~ x, data = ORANGE, FUN = "mean")
YELLOW.sum <- aggregate(y ~ x, data = YELLOW, FUN = "mean")
GREEN.sum <- aggregate(y ~ x, data = GREEN, FUN = "mean")
BLUE.sum <- aggregate(y ~ x, data = BLUE, FUN = "mean")
```

What do I use that would simplify to one generic line of code:

```
w.sum <- aggregate(y ~ x, data = w, FUN = "mean")
```

and cycle through the data names (RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE) assigning the value to 'w'?

Comment: have all the data.frames in a list. and then you can do it in a step

Comment: OR `rbind` all dataframes into a single data with a unique id column representing which data it belongs to. Then perform `group_by` and summarise

Comment: add sample data if you would like us to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to have these as separate variables (See here: [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)).

One option is to keep them in a list, and apply the same function to each with `lapply`:

```
lst <- list(RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE)

sums <- lapply(lst, function(w) aggregate(y ~ x, data = w, FUN = "mean"))
```

However, if the datasets are otherwise similar, you should probably instead combine them into one table with a `color` column. For example:

```
combined <- rbind(cbind(RED, color = "Red"),
                  cbind(ORANGE, color = "Orange"),
                  cbind(YELLOW, color = "Yellow"))

aggregate(y ~ x + color, data = combined, FUN = "mean")
```

An alternative for this last operation (that happens to be a lot faster on large datasets) is to use `group_by` and `summarize` from the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
combined %>%
  group_by(x, color) %>%
  summarize(y = mean(y))
```

Comment: Incredible helpful; thank you for providing the additional information in the link, as well as the various options.